# Product prices only updating after pressing F5

Tags: php

We have a webshop with different customer groups. Depending on what group the customer is in, prices vary. When the logged in customer(customer group with cheaper prices) go's to 'Basket overview' the prices are not correct, when the customer hits F5 the prices are updated to the correct price. The problem could be a cache problem since its updated after a page refresh. After some looking up i added 'ExpiresActive On' in the .htaccess file with the following code but without succes:

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so


# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 month
<filesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

# Set up 2 Hour caching on commonly updated files
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<filesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm|html)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you disable cache form magento back end?

Comment: no, but the cache shouldnt be disabled in production right?The problem is not in the backend, the user gets the wrong price if F5 is not used by the user.

Comment: then disable form backend and then check sure It's working

Comment: Disabling the cache in backend does not solve the problem

Comment: after disabling you flush the data or not?

Comment: yes cache is flushed